# ReactJS removing style tag

Tags: reactjs

I have a ReactJS render function that generates a html element with a style. However, the produced HTML doesn't contain this style. What am I doing wrong?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"
    className={cx('img','box','med','no_img','photo','act')}
    style={{
        backgroundImage : `url:(${config.getUploadUrl()}/${photoDir}/main_${photo})`
    }} />
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="img box med no_img photo act"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `:` after `url` its invalid value for `backgroundImage`